# Propagate exceptions outside of lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I'm having a problem with this code. I expect it to propagate the `InvalidEntityIdException` to the caller of the `getById` method, but it won't:

```java
@Override
public T getById(String id) throws InvalidEntityIdException {
    return computeInTransaction(txn -> {
        EntityId entityId = parseEntityId(id); // throws but not propagated outside computeInTransaction
        Entity entity = txn.getEntity(entityId);
        Class<T> objClass = getEntityClass();
        if (entity != null) {
            return new Unmarshaller<>(objClass, txn).unmarshal(entity);
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

```java
private <R> R computeInTransaction(ComputeTransactionWrapper<R> computeTransactionWrapper) {
    return persistentEntityStore.computeInTransaction(txn -> {
        try {
            return computeTransactionWrapper.compute(txn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (txn != null && !txn.isFinished()) {
                txn.abort();
            }
            sneakyThrow(e);
        } finally {
            if (txn != null) {
                txn.commit();
            }
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

```java
private static void sneakyThrow(Throwable e) {
    EntityBaseRepository.<RuntimeException>sneakyThrow0(e);
}

private static <T extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow0(Throwable e) throws T {
   throw (T)e;
}
```

I checked with the debugger on the line pointing to `sneakyThrow(e)`, and it shows `...exceptions.InvalidEntityIdException: Invalid id was supplied: null`. This is as far as the expected `InvalidEntityIdException` goes. Any hints on why this setup won't work and why the exception won't propagate?